# Problems after failed upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, grub2, data-recovery

I have a Dell series Inspiron 1500, that was born with Ubuntu 14.04 in it. It is a very very cheap notebook, not powerful at all, it is basically an hard disk with a monitor to store university stuff and work on it. I have just had the bad idea to try to upgrade the system to 16.04, but something during installation went wrong (or maybe the computer itself cannot bear the more advanced system, I don't know). Now when I try to access Ubuntu I get a purple screen with flashing light on caps lock. I don't know what it means at all.

Before that, after I switch on, I get a GNU GRUB screen with 4 options:
-Ubuntu
-Advanced options for Ubuntu
-System setup
-Reset the operative system to factory (sorry for bad translation)

As you may have argued, I am not skilled at all in Linux stuff, the only thing I want is to preserve the data I had saved on folders on the Desktop (never did a backup, damn me). I don't mind getting back to 14.04 if necessary, the only thing that matters is to retrieve the data and save them on an external hard disk or a usb to prevent this from happening again...

Comment: @dsstorefile I don't knw. I didn't do anything worrying that I could lose data. You think the last option (restoring the op to factory state) don't do anything to personal data? I don't know much, but the operative system and the usera data should be separate things and resetting the former shouldn't mess the latter, right?

Comment: I'm sorry, I really am a noob at Linux stuff, I use that because it is very useful for university and versitile, but I just got started

Comment: Ok I'll try that later. I was wondering though: given that the computer was born with ubuntu, isn't it possible to just select the last option? I just don't know if returning to factory state affects only the os or also the data.